# integration of discontinuous function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am sure this is an easy question. Although I am new in mathematica. I want to integrate a function that has some (removable) singularities. 
$ f_h(x) = -x\cot{h\pi x} - \frac{1}{\pi h}\sum_{j=1}^{h} \frac{j}{j-hx}$ I want to compute
$\int_{0}^{1}f_h(x)\,dx.$
 I executed the following code

```
f = -x*cot (Pi*x) - 1/(Pi*(1 - x)); Integrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of 1/([Pi](-1+x))-cot [Pi] x^2 does not converge on {0,1}."

Although the answer is $-\frac{\ln{2\pi}}{\pi}.$
How to fix my code to work for general h?

**Answer

```
h = 4; 
g = 1/(h*Pi)* Sum[(i/(i - h*x)), {i, h}]; 
F = - x*Cot[h*Pi*x] - g;
Integrate[F, {x, 0, 1}]
```

we get

> $-\frac{Log[192 \pi^2]}{8\pi}$

Comment: Try `Pi` not `pi` and `Cot[Pi*x]` not `cot (pi*x)`.

Comment: ok. I got the same answer,

Comment: In version 10.1 the input `f = -x*Cot[Pi*x] - 1/(Pi*(1 - x)); Integrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]` gives the output `-(Log[2 Pi]/Pi)`.  Are you seeing something else?

Comment: my bad. When I changed   cot(Pi*x) with   Cot[Pi*x] I got the right result.

Answer (score 1):

Include the option `PrincipalValue -> True`:

```
Integrate[-x Cot[π x] -1/(π (1-x)), {x, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue->True]
```

> -(Log[2 π]/π)

Comment: @111 I don't think there's a principal value for $h>1$, since the pole at $x=1$ doesn't cancel.